# Magento 2: How do I check If custom options exists for product?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, custom

I am inserting custom options programmatically for multiple products from some template where I add options and assign them to products But when I edit those options and assigned it to more products then it double added for previously assigned products. 
How can I check if that custom option is already assigned or exists for any product so it will only edit for that product.

I can't add whole code here and yes, I am referring below link but my options are dynamic.
    https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-option-programmatically-in-magento2/

Answer (score 0):

Based in the code of webkul.com you have these options:

**Load Product**

```
$product = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
```

**Custom Options**

```
$customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
```

**Configurable Options**

```
$productTypeInstance = $_objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
         $productAttributeOptions = $productTypeInstance->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
```

The last step is check based in *Custom or Configurable Options* if your option is created in product before and keep it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private $productRepository;

public function __construct(
   -------------
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
   -------------
) {
  $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function hasOptionsProduct()
{
  $sku = '24-WG080';
 
  $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
  $hasOptions = $product->hasOptions();
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if custom options exist for a product in Magento 2, you can follow these steps:

1. Inject the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory` class into your class constructor. Open the class file where you want to perform the check (e.g., a block class or a custom module class).

```php
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory;

class CustomClass
{
    protected $optionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        OptionFactory $optionFactory
    ) {
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
    }

    // ...
}
```

2. In your class, create a public function to check if custom options exist for a product. Add the following code to your class:

```php
public function hasCustomOptions($productId)
{
    $productOptions = $this->optionFactory->create()->getProductOptionCollection($productId);
    return $productOptions->getSize() > 0;
}
```

3. Now, you can use the `hasCustomOptions` function to check if custom options exist for a specific product ID. For example, in a template file, you can call this function by passing the product ID and perform the necessary actions based on the result.

```html
<?php if ($block->hasCustomOptions($productId)) : ?>
    <!-- Custom options exist for the product -->
    <p>Custom options are available.</p>
<?php else : ?>
    <!-- No custom options for the product -->
    <p>No custom options available.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

By following these steps, you can check if custom options exist for a product in Magento 2. The `OptionFactory` class provides methods to fetch and manipulate custom options associated with a product.

Answer (score 0):

To check if custom options exist for a product in Magento 2, you can use the following code:

```php
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory;

class CustomClass
{
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $optionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        OptionFactory $optionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
    }

    public function hasCustomOptions($productId)
    {
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
            $customOptions = $this->optionFactory->create()->getProductOptionCollection($product);
            return count($customOptions) > 0;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            // Handle exception if the product does not exist
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how you can use the above code:

1. Inject the `ProductRepositoryInterface` and `OptionFactory` classes into your class constructor.
2. In the `hasCustomOptions` function, first, retrieve the product using the `ProductRepositoryInterface` by passing the product ID.
3. Use the `OptionFactory` to create an instance of the product options.
4. Get the custom options collection by calling the `getProductOptionCollection` method on the options instance and passing the product as an argument.
5. Check if the count of custom options is greater than zero. If it is, it means custom options exist for the product.
6. If an exception of type `NoSuchEntityException` is thrown, it means the product does not exist. Handle the exception appropriately and return `false`.

You can call the `hasCustomOptions` function and pass the product ID to check if custom options exist for a specific product:

```php
$productId = 123; // Replace with your product ID
$customClass = new CustomClass($productRepository, $optionFactory);
if ($customClass->hasCustomOptions($productId)) {
    // Custom options exist for the product
    // Perform your actions here
} else {
    // No custom options for the product
}
```

Make sure to replace `$productRepository` and `$optionFactory` with the actual instances of the respective classes in your code.